# Flexslider and content with Form

Tags: javascript, flexslider

I'm having an unusual issue with Flexsider and a form in one of the slides. The form has some radio buttons in it and not much else other than some divs for containers. Clicking on a radio button results in the cursor outline around the button, so it is responding, but it will not be checked. I did try a test using a javascript call to set the property. Walking through, it set the radio button successfully, but after exiting the function, the radio button was reset. I cannot seem to find any similar issues discussed here or elsewhere and am completely flabbergasted.

The form content is loaded through ajax. I noticed that Flexslider creates clones of the first and last slides and the clone was getting updated when the ajax content was loaded into the slide. I reordered my slides so there would be no clone of the form but could still not check the radio button. However, in Firebug, I set the checked property to true (using jquery in the Watch panel) and the button, this time, remained checked. Trying to check/uncheck resulted in no effect and the button whose property I had set through Firebug remained.

**Edit**: I added an textfield and that worked without issue.

Following is the HTML. The javascript is, honestly, negligible as it is only an ajax request to get the form content. Javascript in use is jquery, flexslider, and flowplayer for the video. The form is located in data-slide 2, officially the second one as the first is the clone.

```
<section class="slider">
    <div class="flexslider" id="mainSlider">

        <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
            <ul class="slides" style="width: 1000%; margin-left: -3486px;">
                <li data-slide="2" data-type="Quiz" data-id="6" class="clone" style="width: 1162px; float: left; display: block;">

                    <div class="quiz" data-id="1">
                        <div class="quizDescription">

                        </div>
                        <div class="quizContent" data-id="1">
                            <div style="max-width: " data-id="1" class="question">
                                <div class="questionText">Is TRUE true?<br></div>
                                    <span id="CourseQuizAnswer"><input type="radio" name="CourseQuizAnswer" id="CourseQuizAnswer_0" value="2"> 
                                        <label for="CourseQuizAnswer_0" style="display:inline">True</label><br>
                                        <input type="radio" name="CourseQuizAnswer" id="CourseQuizAnswer_1" value="3">
                                        <label for="CourseQuizAnswer_1" style="display:inline">False</label>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="well">
                            <input type="button" value="Submit" name="yt0" onclick="submitQuestionAnswer(this);" class="btn btn-primary btn-med">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </li>
                <li data-slide="0" data-type="Video" data-id="2" style="width: 1162px; float: left; display: block;" class="">

                    <div class="minimalist video-slide flowplayer is-mouseout is-ready is-paused" data-video_id="1" id="mainPlayer">
                        <video tabindex="0" class="fp-engine">
                            <source src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
                        </video>
                        <div class="fp-ratio" style="padding-top: 56.25%;"></div>      <div class="fp-ui">         <div class="fp-waiting"><em></em><em></em><em></em></div>         <a class="fp-fullscreen"></a>         <a class="fp-unload"></a>         <p class="fp-speed"></p>         <div class="fp-controls">            <a class="fp-play"></a>            <div class="fp-timeline" style="">               <div class="fp-buffer" style="width: 100%;"></div>               <div class="fp-progress"></div>            </div>            <div class="fp-volume">               <a class="fp-mute"></a>               <div class="fp-volumeslider" style="">                  <div class="fp-volumelevel" style="width: 43%;"></div>               </div>            </div>         </div>         <div class="fp-time">            <em class="fp-elapsed">00:00</em>            <em class="fp-remaining">00:40</em>            <em class="fp-duration">00:40</em>         </div>         <div class="fp-message"><h2></h2><p></p></div>      </div><a href="http://flowplayer.org" target="_top"></a></div>
                </li>
                <li data-slide="1" data-type="Content" data-id="5" style="width: 1162px; float: left; display: block;">
                    Segment 2            
                </li>
                <li data-slide="2" data-type="Quiz" data-id="6" class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 1162px; float: left; display: block;">
                    <div class="quiz" data-id="1">
                        <div class="quizDescription">

                        </div>
                        <div class="quizContent" data-id="1">
                            <div style="max-width: " data-id="1" class="question">
                                <div class="questionText">
                                    Is TRUE true?<br>
                                </div>
                                <span id="CourseQuizAnswer">
                                    <input type="radio" name="CourseQuizAnswer" id="CourseQuizAnswer_0" value="2"> 
                                    <label for="CourseQuizAnswer_0" style="display:inline">True</label><br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="CourseQuizAnswer" id="CourseQuizAnswer_1" value="3"> 
                                    <label for="CourseQuizAnswer_1" style="display:inline">False</label>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="well">
                            <input type="button" value="Submit" name="yt0" onclick="submitQuestionAnswer(this);" class="btn btn-primary btn-med">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </li>
                <li data-slide="0" data-type="Video" data-id="2" style="width: 1162px; float: left; display: block;" class="clone">

                    <div class="minimalist video-slide" data-video_id="1" id="mainPlayer">
                        <video tabindex="0">
                            <source src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Does anyone have any insight? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your code and/or make a fiddle.

Comment: Code added as requested. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate `id`s for radio buttons. Remove the duplicate `id`s and try it again. Let me know if it still isn't working.

For example:

```
<input type="radio" name="CourseQuizAnswer" id="CourseQuizAnswer_0" value="2">
```

is the same as

```
<input type="radio" name="CourseQuizAnswer" id="CourseQuizAnswer_0" value="2">
```

and it exists twice on the page.

I know why you may have thought that your `id`s were unique: you made them unique for the question that they pertain to to. However, the you forgot to make them unique on the page. The problem is that `id`s are all in the global page scope, regardless of where they are declared.

Good luck! :)

Comment: The IDs are unique, they are appended _0 and _1 respectively. The name attributes are the same, however.

Comment: I just moved my responses to your comment to my answer

Comment: Now I see what you mean. The flexslider does that for animationLoop, it clones the end slides. So I turned that off, which means that now those IDs are unique and still nothing. I added an onclick function call to set the checked property and set a breakpoint right after setting the property. At that point, the radio button is set and visibly on, but as soon as we exit the function, the radio buttons get cleared.

Comment: Also, please post your JavaScript

Comment: I solved this issue with further thought into what was happening. Honestly, I'm still not certain that this is not caused by Flexslider, but added a 'stopPropagation' on the event when clicked and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

flexslider creates a mirror copy of each slide to create the illusion of continuity when scrolling past through the last slide. These are created with a class name "clone". You can try to disable the forms before submit using jQuery:

```
$(".clone input").prop("disabled", true);
```